# Null Pointer Exception while unmarshalling XML to Java object having @XMLElementWrapper

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB for unmarshalling XML file to Java Object.

This XML contains list. e.g

```
<items>
<item>
...
</item>
...
</items>
```

and Java Class have @XMLElementWrapper for items

```
@XMLElementWrapper(name="items")
@XMLElement(name="item")
private List<Item> items;
```

And I am getting null pointer exception when i try to unmarshall.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
          at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:54)
          at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
          at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.get(Accessor.java:185)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:249)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:224)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:78)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:150)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:404)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:125)
          at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
          at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
          at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
          at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
          at com.amazon.epubs.edition.manifest.serializer.JAXBMarshaller.unmarshall(JAXBMarshaller.java:45)
          at amazon.PeriodicalsManagementService.handler.PreviewPublicationHandler.getFolioRenditions(PreviewPublicationHandler.java:293)
          at amazon.PeriodicalsManagementService.handler.PreviewPublicationHandler.doMainProcessing(PreviewPublicationHandler.java:176)
          ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your application and what environment you are running in?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a wrapper class for the `List<>`:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Items {
    @XmlElement
    List<Item> item;
}
```

Then do the `unmarshall` for the `Items`

Comment: Package in which this class is present in dependency to my package (where i am tring to unmarshall). I cannot change this class, because there may be other package which are already using this as dependency and in addition i dont own this package.


If add dependency of JAXB2.2 to my package, this problem is solved. I am facing this problem only because of older version of Jaxb. Again it will be really difficult to change this version (limitations of our build system) . 

Is there any other library like jaxb which can understand Jaxb annotations and unmarshall/marshall xml-java?

Comment: Yes of course. That is `xstream`. Almost similar. [Check it here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html)

Comment: Stackoverflow questions and discussion are at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xstream)